# open image in another app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wallpaper

**this is how my app look:**

[image]

**this is what i want to perform on button click: open image in another app**

[image]

**this is what i tried:**

```
package com.example.wallpaper_test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class WallpaperScreenActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper_layout);

        // image resource
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pop);

        // call installed wallpaper app to set wallpaper on button click
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View vx) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);                
                intent.setDataAndType(uri.setreso, "image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
                this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));

            }

        });

    }

}
```

**those errors i got:**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

uri cannot be resolved to a variable    WallpaperScreenActivity.java    /Wallpaper_Test/src/com/example/wallpaper_test  line 32 Java Problem

The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} WallpaperScreenActivity.java    /Wallpaper_Test/src/com/example/wallpaper_test  line 34 Java Problem
```

i created a very simple app in which i am showing an image in image_view and i want to open this image in another app on button click.

Comment: Just remove this from this.startActivity(), just use startActivity()

Comment: Your code is right, you just need to pass a valid Uri to the Intent. What is the Uri you want to pass?

Comment: actually i want to pass image so i can open it with another app

Comment: how do i pass image-view image to uri

Comment: Did you resolved your issue?

Comment: i tried this:
`Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.wallpaper_test/drawable/pop"),"image/*");
startActivity(intent);`

and got unfortunately app stopped error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first i saved image to sd card then open it using this below code

```
// open image in another app
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/temp_image0.png"),"image/*");
                    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
                    //
```